# How can the phenotypic effects of a tumor suppressor mutation be silenced?

Tags: genetics, cancer, mutations

I've been reading a little about the "two-hit" hypothesis for tumor suppressor genes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumor_suppressor_gene#Two-hit_hypothesis), which mentions that some genes exhibiting haploinsufficiency are exceptions to the hypothesis. I've read elsewhere on this site (namely the answer to [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/20404/13127)) that suggests haplosufficiency as a means of "silencing" the mutation of the tumor suppressor gene such that the expression of the wild-type allele compensates for the mutant allele.

Are there any other mechanisms that contribute to incomplete penetrance of tumor suppressor mutations?

Answer (score 1):

*This is more of a comment*

---

Mutation in tumour suppressor is a recessive trait and there is no active "silencing" of the mutation. If a tumour suppressor is a TF then a mutation in the DNA binding domain can have no effect if there is a complementary mutation in its binding site. This is just a theoretical possibility and I have not heard of any examples as such. I don't think any other mechanisms exist for "silencing" any loss of function mutation.